How can I set Ansible command arguments based on what keys a loop item has?
Context
I'm using Ansible to setup Windows servers using the win_chocolatey module.
In my group_vars/windows_servers.yml file I have:
choco_packages:
  - 7zip
  - git
  - vscode

And in my playbook task I have:
- name: Install and upgrade software using Chocolatey
  hosts: windows_servers
  tasks:
    - name: Install latest package versions
      chocolatey.chocolatey.win_chocolatey:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: latest
      loop: "{{ choco_packages }}"

So far, so good.
However, now I have some packages where I need to install a specific version and/or I need to pass certain install arguments.
I can create three lists in my group_vars/windows_servers.yml, one for each goal (latest package, specific version, package with parameters) and have three tasks which are fed by each list, setting the appropriate keys.
But to reduce the maintenance burden, I would rather have a single list of packages where I optionally set the required keys and have 1 task that, sets the appropriate options  depending on available item keys. E.g.:
choco_packages:
  - { name: "7zip", version: "22.1" }
  - { name: "git" , install_args: [ "/NoGuiHereIntegration", "/NoGitLfs"] }
  - { name: "vscode" }

Question
How should I write the Ansible task to set the version and install arguments if they are provided, and install the latest version if not? I am hoping to find something along the lines of **kwargs in Python.
What I've tried
Using the when: conditional I can create three tasks that that handle the applicable list part:
- name: Install and upgrade software using Chocolatey
  hosts: windows_servers
  tasks:
    - name: Install latest versions
      chocolatey.chocolatey.win_chocolatey:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        state: latest
      loop: "{{ choco_packages }}"
      when: item.version is not defined and item.install_args is not defined
    - name: Install specific versions
      chocolatey.chocolatey.win_chocolatey:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        version: "{{ item.version }}"
        state: present
      loop: "{{ choco_packages }}"
      when: item.version is defined
    - name: Install with parameters
      chocolatey.chocolatey.win_chocolatey:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        install_args: "{{ item.install_args }}"
        state: present
      loop: "{{ choco_packages }}"
      when: item.install_args is defined

But this does not handle combinations of version and install_args and is rather verbose.

You'll want to make use of a loop, and the default filter with "omit" (as demonstrated in the docs on optional variables).
Something like this...
 - name: Install stuff
   chocolatey.chocolatey.win_chocolatey:
     name: "{{ item.name }}"
     state: "{{ item.version is defined | ternary('present','latest') }}"
     version: "{{ item.version | default(omit) }}"
     package_params: "{{ item.package_params | default(omit) }}"
     install_args: "{{ item.install_args | default(omit) }}"
     choco_args: "{{ item.choco_args | default(omit) }}"

   loop: "{{ choco_packages }}"

This will work with this var modified from your original.
choco_packages:
 - { name: "7zip", version: "22.1" }
 - { name: "git" , package_params: "/NoGuiHereIntegration /NoGitLfs"}
 - { name: "vscode" }

This SHOULD:

Install a specified version if the version is defined (the ternary filter will return "present" when version is defined, otherwise it will return "latest"
package_params will only be passed if its defined
choco_args will only be passed if its defined
version will only be passed if it is defined.

Unrelated, but it looks like you were trying to pass a list to install_args which according to the documentation, only takes a string.
Be sure to double-check which you're trying to pass (a parameter to the package (package_params), a parameter directly through to the installer (install_args), or a parameter to choco.exe (choco_args)

Thanks! I wrote the example args as an example and did not actually try to run it, but thanks for pointing out my type error. Would you mind sharing how you could quickly see what should be an install_args  or a choco_args?

The package (at least a well written one) will tell you what parameters it supports.

Oh, should've been more clear, I meant not what arguments a package/installer accepts, but (knowing the arguments) where they should go: into the install_args or the choco_args. Or is as it as simple as: everything that would go as an argument for choco install <package> --params goes into choco_args?

Exactly --package-params go into choco_args and --install-arguments go into install_args

The only required parameter in win_chocolatey is name. Other parameters are optional. Use the filter default(alias: d) and the special omit variable to omit undefined parameters. See Omitting Parameters.
For example, the task below should do what you want
    - chocolatey.chocolatey.win_chocolatey:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        version: "{{ item.version | d(omit) }}"
        install_args: "{{ item.install_args | d(omit) }}"
        state: "{{ item.state | d(omit) }}"
      loop: "{{ choco_packages }}"

Notes:

This way, you can use other module parameters as needed (potentially all).
In your code state: present is redundant because the default value of the parameter state is present.
You can redefine the defaults if you want to. For example,

        state: "{{ item.state | d('latest') }}"


In your question, it is not clear how you decide which state shall be used.  You put the attribute state into the choco_packages, or you can define a variable for this purpose. For example, the below declaration keeps all options open

        state: "{{ item.state | d(my_state|d('present')) }}"




The parameter install_args requires a string.


